How to install c++17 library in /usr/include/c++/?
$ gcc -v
gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 

$ ls /usr/include/c++
10 11

My os version is ubuntu 22.04, gcc version is 11.4.0
I need to include a c++ 17 library located under /usr/include/c++, but I'm not sure where to find it.
Where should I download the library for c++ 17 and install in  /usr/include/c++ ?

try to ./configure  after unpack it, and make and make install .    But why not try to find apt to install it for you ? sudo apt install libmpfr-dev libgmp3-dev libmpc-dev -y

don't install anything in /usr/include/c++, it's a system directory, non-system files should be in /usr/local/include

apt-cache search KeyWord for searching something ... include library... and not just library.

The version number in /usr/include/c++ is not about the C++ standard version, but the compiler version. The compiler can be asked to use a particular C++ standard, and then it will pull the correct headers for that version from the subdirectory that it owns in /usr/include/c++. Use -std=c++17 to do that.

Thanks all ,I know where the problem is, have a good day.

If your compiler doesn't support C++17 core features, the std libray alone won't help. std library is built around core abilities.
